# Prevent estimated time of arrival degradation with Android GPS

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps, location

I'm getting estimated time of arrival (ETA) from point A to point B using the Google Maps API's onLocationChanged callback Location data.

I can easily derive the ETA using the t = d/v formula but I want to prevent the time estimate from degrading to infinity once the car slows down or stops during the travel.

I was thinking of preserving the best case ETA in a variable and update it if any major change in speed occurs.

Any thoughts on a suitable algorithm for this?

Answer (score 2):

when querying or calculating the ETA you should not use the current speed (which can be 0), but use instead the average speed over the last 3 (or x) minutes.